# Subtract an interval from a time value

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I want to get the time 1 hour before the current time in PostgreSQL. How can I do that?

Say, for example, currently the time is `'17:37:06'`, then I want the result output as `'16:37:06'`

Answer (score 25):

If you really only want the time, use `current_time` `current_timestamp` or `now()` will return a date as well.

```
select current_time - interval '1' hour
```

or to subtract one hour and 25 minutes:

```
select current_time - interval '1:25'
```

(note that you need to remove the `hour` keyword if you use an interval with hours *and* minutes)

If you do want the date to be part of the result, just replace `current_time` with `current_timestamp`.

Comment: `interval`'s additional option resticts the set of stored fields, so essentially `interval '1:25' hour` equals to 1 hour -- `interval '1:25'` & `interval '1:25 hour'` are valid alternatives. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2346

Comment: @pozs: thanks, corrected (btw: I use `interval '1' hour` because that is the format defined by the SQL standard)

Comment: That's understandable -- using the SQL standard, you could write `interval '1:25' hour to minute` or using the iso 8601 (date/time standard)  `interval 'PT1H25M'`, but in my opinion these are harder to read.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `interval` type to do arithmetic on `date` types

```
select now() - interval '1 hour';
```

It is possible to use fractions like 1 hour and a half

```
select now() - 1.5 * interval '1 hour';
```

Comment: I am getting this: Error executing SELECT statement. ERROR: column "interval" does not exist
  Position: 16